# Renamed C# project, can't get rid of the old dll

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am writing a Web API application. To begin with, I created the project and gave it a short name, like pnlink.csproj which compiled into pnlink.dll - all OK so far.
Then at one point I decided to rename the project and dll into something a bit more fitting the rest of my naming scheme and the project file became pnlink.Rest.Api.csproj. Also, Assembly Name and Default Namespace were changed accordingly.

Today I noticed that the bin directory contains the old pnlink.dll (which wasn't touched in several months, according to the filesystem information). The new pnlink.Rest.Api.dll is also present and is newly touched. I removed the old pnlink.dll and saw that the application is not able to run any more. It compiles fine, but in runtime I get the 404 message when I navigate to the root (instead of going to the default controller (which only produces some welcome message)). Other navigation paths work fine, actually.

I can find no references to pnlink.csproj or pnlink.dll or anything like that *anywhere* in the application code. 
I of course tried to delete all compilation results (obj, bin) and compile everything from scratch, all to no avail.

Any ideas are much appreciated!

Comment: Maybe the dll is GAC'ed?

Comment: Have you opened all of your project files in a text editor to see if there are any references hidden in the project xml?

Comment: Have you also looked in your web.config/app.config files to see if it has been referenced there also?

Comment: @Adrian: yes, i have, actually - nothing.

Comment: @meda, which one would it be and how do I tell? rebuilding the app would have helped though, anyway, no?

Comment: Since the application compiles, have you tried to debug it? I am wondering if perhaps your route configuration is no longer correct or not even being loaded, and hence your 404. If you haven't tried it yet, put a break point in the Application_Start() in the Global.asax and make sure that the route configuration loads.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I've got it... What an idiotic situation. 
The new assembly's HomeController was incorrectly inherited from ApiController and did not produce the right output on the root URL. Somehow when the old dll was in the bin folder, it managed to hook up to the handling of the request and handle the root properly. 
Sorry about confusing everybody and thank you for the input!

Comment: Cool. This is what my thought path was taking me to. I'm glad you resolved it.